# separate text and store in a list to bind in repeater in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a text called `Default/css`. I want  a value `Default` and `css` separated by `/` and  store in a list.Later this list is bind in a repeater. I know how to bind in repeater but I don't know how to separate text and store in a list. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<string> list = yourString.Split('/').ToList();
```

make sure that you're working with at least C# 3.0 ver

Comment: thanks a lot it works .May u suggest how to clear a list before insert new data.Thanks.